# Creating String from a bitmask

Tags: java, android

In my Android app I store days of week in an `int` variable by using bit masking.

I'm using the following `SparseIntArray` to get the day flags for the corresponding days:

```
public static final SparseIntArray DAY_FLAGS = new SparseIntArray(7);
static {
    DAYS.put(Calendar.MONDAY, 1);
    DAYS.put(Calendar.TUESDAY, 2);
    DAYS.put(Calendar.WEDNESDAY, 4);
    DAYS.put(Calendar.THURSDAY, 8);
    DAYS.put(Calendar.FRIDAY, 16);
    DAYS.put(Calendar.SATURDAY, 32);
    DAYS.put(Calendar.SUNDAY, 64);
}
```

I'd like to be able to create `String` from a mask, for example:

> int value - `String`
>
> ---
>
> 1 - "Mon"
>
> 42 - "Tue Thu Sat"
>
> 127 - "Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun"

For this I'm using the following method:

```
public static String maskToString(Context context, int mask, int firstDayOfWeek) {
    List<Integer> dayList = new ArrayList<>(7);

    // The idea is to iterate through the SparseIntArray and check
    // if the bit in the mask is set for the particular day.
    // If it is, add that day to the dayList.
    for (int i = 0; i < DAY_FLAGS.size(); i++) {
        if (isFlagSet(DAY_FLAGS.valueAt(i), mask)) {
            dayList.add(DAY_FLAGS.keyAt(i));
        }
    }

    // Sort the days by taking the first day of the week into account
    Collections.sort(dayList, new DayComparator(firstDayOfWeek));

    // This List will contain the individual Strings for the days
    List<String> dayStringList = new ArrayList<>(dayList.size());

    // dayToString() simply returns a String resource for a given day
    for (Integer day : dayList) {
        dayStringList.add(dayToString(context, day));
    }

    // join the individual Strings into a single String
    return TextUtils.join(" ", dayStringList);
}
```

The `isFlagSet()` method simply checks if a given flag is set in a given mask:

```
private static boolean isFlagSet(int flag, int mask) {
    return ((mask & flag) == flag);
}
```

My `maskToString()` method seems clumsy (mostly in terms of unnecessary(?) object creation). I believe it can be optimized, I just don't know how.

(I can use only Java 7 features, no Java 8)

I'd appreciate any advice.

**EDIT:**

One thing I came up with regarding optimization is to create a `static final DayComparator` instance and pass the `firstDayOfWeek` variable in a setter (instead of the constructor):

```
private static final DayComparator DAY_COMPARATOR = new DayComparator();

public static String maskToString(Context context, int mask, int firstDayOfWeek) {
    List<Integer> dayList = new ArrayList<>(7);

    for (int i = 0; i < DAY_FLAGS.size(); i++) {
        if (isFlagSet(DAY_FLAGS.valueAt(i), mask)) {
            dayList.add(DAY_FLAGS.keyAt(i));
        }
    }

    // so we do not create a new object here every time the method is called
    DAY_COMPARATOR.setFirstDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);
    Collections.sort(days, DAY_COMPARATOR);

    List<String> dayStringList = new ArrayList<>(dayList.size());

    for (Integer day : dayList) {
        dayStringList.add(dayToString(context, day));
    }

    return TextUtils.join(" ", dayStringList);
}
```

What do you think? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Current approach

You can determine the exact count of days in the mask beforehand -> you can use a better initial size than `7` for the array list (or directly an array as the size is fixed).
You don't have to sort the list (and thus don't need the comparator), rotating based on the `firstDayOfTheWeek` is sufficient as the order of the days does not change.
While this is very ugly: You could replace the `new ArrayList<>(dayList.size())` with `(List<String>)(List<?>)dayList`.

Regarding your edit: This seems like a very bad idea if you ever want to make your app multithreaded.

#### Alternative implementation

You can avoid rotating the resulting list if you start interpreting the `mask` at the provided `firstDayOfWeek` instead of `Monday`.

```
public static final int MONDAY    = 0x01;
public static final int TUESDAY   = 0x02;
public static final int WEDNESDAY = 0x04;
public static final int THURSDAY  = 0x08;
public static final int FRIDAY    = 0x10;
public static final int SATURDAY  = 0x20;
public static final int SUNDAY    = 0x40;

public static String maskToString(int mask, int firstDayOfWeek) {
    assert (mask & ~127 | firstDayOfWeek & ~127
            | firstDayOfWeek & firstDayOfWeek - 1) == 0;
    String[] values = new String[bitCount(mask)];
    int i = 0, d = firstDayOfWeek;
    do {
        if ((mask & d) != 0)
            values[i++] = dayToString(d);
    } while ((d = d << 1 & 127 | d >> 6) != firstDayOfWeek);
    return Strings.join(" ", values, true);
}
```

Which gives the following result:

```
maskToString(MONDAY, MONDAY);                              // Mon
maskToString(TUESDAY | THURSDAY | SATURDAY, MONDAY);       // Tue Thu Sat
maskToString(TUESDAY | THURSDAY | SATURDAY, SUNDAY);       // Tue Thu Sat
maskToString(TUESDAY | THURSDAY | SUNDAY, MONDAY);         // Tue Thu Sun
maskToString(TUESDAY | THURSDAY | SUNDAY, SUNDAY);         // Sun Tue Thu
maskToString(127, MONDAY);      // Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
maskToString(127, SUNDAY);      // Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
maskToString(127, WEDNESDAY);   // Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue
```